# Not Sure Where To Update The Display - PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making The Snake Game, and in this game, when the snake hits a piece of food, the length of the snake increase. The issue that I'm having is that when I implemented some code that will help me make the snake's length longer and tested it out, the snake was moving behind the scenes but wasn't showing up. I know I have to update the display, but I don't know where.

PYTHON

```
# IMPORT
import pygame, random, time, sys

# GLOBALS
global screen, displayW, displayH
global clock, FPS, end, font
global snake, food, gameOverText

# SETGLOBALVALUES
def setGlobalValues():
    global screen, displayW, displayH
    global clock, FPS, end, font
    global snake, food, gameOverText

    displayW = 600
    displayH = 400
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((displayW, displayH))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 15
    end = False
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("robotomono", 40)

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()

    gameOverText = Text()
    gameOverText.text = "GAME OVER"
    gameOverText.color = (255, 0, 0)

# SNAKE
class Snake():
    def __init__(self, leadX=0, leadY=0, velX=0, velY=0, change=0, w=0, h=0, color=(), list=[], head=[]):
        self.leadX = displayW / 2
        self.leadY = displayH / 2
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.change = 10
        self.w = 10
        self.h = 10
        self.list = []
        self.head = []
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)

    def draw(self):
        for XnY in self.list:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (XnY[0], XnY[1], self.w, self.h))

    def animate(self):
        self.leadX += self.velX
        self.leadY += self.velY

    def collision(self):
        # collision with wall
        if self.leadX < 0 or self.leadX + self.w > displayW or self.leadY < 0 or self.leadY + self.h > displayH:
            gameOverText.draw()
            exit()

        # collision with food
        if self.leadX >= food.x and self.leadX <= food.x + food.w and self.leadY >= food.y and self.leadY <= food.y:
            food.reset()

# FOOD
class Food():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, w=0, h=0, color=()):
        self.w = 10
        self.h = 10
        self.x = round(random.randrange(0, displayW - self.w) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.y = round(random.randrange(0, displayH - self.h) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.color = (0, 200, 0)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    def reset(self):
        self.x = round(random.randrange(0, displayW - self.w) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.y = round(random.randrange(0, displayH - self.h) / 10.0) * 10.0

        self.draw()

# TEXT
class Text():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, text="", color=()):
        self.x = displayW / 2 - 100
        self.y = displayH / 2 - 50
        self.text = ""
        self.color = ()

    def draw(self):
        render = font.render(self.text, True, self.color)

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(render, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.update()

        time.sleep(2)

# MAIN
def main():
    pygame.init()

    setGlobalValues()
    setup()
    gameLoop()
    quit()

# GAMELOOP
def gameLoop():
    global end

    while not end:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # QUIT
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                end = True

            # KEYDOWN
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    snake.velX -= snake.change
                    snake.velY = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.velX += snake.change
                    snake.velY = 0

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    snake.velY -= snake.change
                    snake.velX = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    snake.velY += snake.change
                    snake.velX = 0

        draw()
        animate()
        collision()

        setFPS()

# DRAW
def draw():
    # fill background
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    snake.head.append(snake.leadX)
    snake.head.append(snake.leadY)
    snake.list.append(snake.head)

    snake.draw()
    food.draw()

    # update
    pygame.display.update()

# ANIMATE
def animate():
    snake.animate()

# COLLISION
def collision():
    snake.collision()

# SETUP
def setup():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

# SETFPS
def setFPS():
    clock.tick(FPS)

# QUIT
def exit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# CALL MAIN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: use [pygame.Rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep size and position of food and snake elements - `Rect` has methods to check collisions and you can use `rect.right` instead of `food.w + food.w`  and draw `draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)`

Comment: if snake element has size 10, and move is 10 then you can keep all elements on list (first element is head) and when it moves you add new element at beginning of list, and remove last element. When it eats apple you don't remove last element once - and snake will be longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` is in correct place.

I moved some code from `draw()` to `snake.animate()` and added `make_longer = True/False` and now snake is making longer when it eats apple.

```
# IMPORT
import pygame, random, time, sys

# GLOBALS
global screen, displayW, displayH
global clock, FPS, end, font
global snake, food, gameOverText

# SETGLOBALVALUES
def setGlobalValues():
    global screen, displayW, displayH
    global clock, FPS, end, font
    global snake, food, gameOverText

    displayW = 600
    displayH = 400
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((displayW, displayH))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 5
    end = False
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("robotomono", 40)

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()

    gameOverText = Text()
    gameOverText.text = "GAME OVER"
    gameOverText.color = (255, 0, 0)

# SNAKE
class Snake():
    def __init__(self, leadX=0, leadY=0, velX=0, velY=0, change=0, w=0, h=0, color=(), list=[], head=[]):
        self.leadX = displayW / 2
        self.leadY = displayH / 2
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.change = 10
        self.w = 10
        self.h = 10
        self.list = []
        self.head = []
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)

        self.make_longer = True

    def draw(self):
        for x, y in self.list:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (x, y, self.w, self.h))

    def animate(self):
        self.leadX += self.velX
        self.leadY += self.velY

        # add first element
        self.head = [self.leadX, self.leadY]  # <--
        self.list.insert(0, snake.head)       # <--

        if not self.make_longer:      # <--
            # remove last element     # <-- 
            del snake.list[-1]        # <--
        else:                         # <--
            self.make_longer = False  # <--

    def collision(self):
        # collision with wall
        if self.leadX < 0 or self.leadX + self.w > displayW or self.leadY < 0 or self.leadY + self.h > displayH:
            gameOverText.draw()
            exit()

        # collision with food
        if self.leadX >= food.x and self.leadX <= food.x + food.w and self.leadY >= food.y and self.leadY <= food.y:
            food.reset()
            self.make_longer = True # <--

# FOOD
class Food():

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, w=0, h=0, color=()):
        self.w = 10
        self.h = 10
        self.x = round(random.randrange(0, displayW - self.w) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.y = round(random.randrange(0, displayH - self.h) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.color = (0, 200, 0)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    def reset(self):
        self.x = round(random.randrange(0, displayW - self.w) / 10.0) * 10.0
        self.y = round(random.randrange(0, displayH - self.h) / 10.0) * 10.0

# TEXT
class Text():

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, text="", color=()):
        self.x = displayW / 2 - 100
        self.y = displayH / 2 - 50
        self.text = ""
        self.color = ()

    def draw(self):
        render = font.render(self.text, True, self.color)

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(render, (self.x, self.y))
        pygame.display.update()

        time.sleep(2)

# MAIN
def main():
    pygame.init()

    setGlobalValues()
    setup()
    gameLoop()
    quit()

# GAMELOOP
def gameLoop():
    global end

    while not end:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # QUIT
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                end = True

            # KEYDOWN
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    snake.velX -= snake.change
                    snake.velY = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.velX += snake.change
                    snake.velY = 0

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    snake.velY -= snake.change
                    snake.velX = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    snake.velY += snake.change
                    snake.velX = 0

        draw()
        animate()
        collision()

        setFPS()

# DRAW
def draw():
    # fill background
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    snake.draw()
    food.draw()

    # update
    pygame.display.update()

# ANIMATE
def animate():
    snake.animate()


# COLLISION
def collision():
    snake.collision()

# SETUP
def setup():
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

# SETFPS
def setFPS():
    clock.tick(FPS)

# QUIT
def exit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# CALL MAIN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

**BTW:** drawing red head and black tail

```
def draw(self):
    # draw head
    x, y = self.list[0]
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, self.w, self.h))

    # draw tail
    for x, y in self.list[1:]:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (x, y, self.w, self.h))
```